How do I keep a reference to an object after creating it in a for loop
I am creating multiple objects in a for loop and would like to keep one of these objects after the loop is finished to access some attributes. Is there a way to do this without creating a deep copy? Can I just save the address of the object in the if statement?
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    int x = 0;
    myObject obj = new MyObject();

    obj.Method1 //Contains random numbers

    if (obj.Attribute > x)
    {
        //Save the object?
    }
}

//Access the object with the highest attribute


Is there a way to prevent the deletion of the previous object when the new one is created in the for loop?

Declare a variable before the loop to hold the result (you need to move the x initialization here, too):
MyObject result = null;
int x = int.MinValue;
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    myObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.Method1 //Contains random numbers

    if (obj.Attribute > x)
    {
        result = obj;
    }
}

And for fun, if you can make the MyObject constructor call Method1() for you:
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).
      Select(i => new MyObject()).
      Max( Comparer<MyObject>.Create((a,b) => a.Attribute.CompareTo(b.Attribute)));

Fiddle
And if you can't change MyObject:
var result = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).
      Select(i => {
         var obj = new MyObject();
         obj.Method1();
         return obj;
      }).
      Max( Comparer<MyObject>.Create((a,b) => a.Attribute.CompareTo(b.Attribute)));


because of "definite assignment", you'll need to assign MyObject result = null; initially, else you won't be able to read the variable after the loop

@MarcGravell Duh. Fixed it :)

Hehe, the guy wants to look at the moon and you tell him how to build a rocket :-)

@PoulBak I like rockets :)
